# Angular navigateByUrl with huge delay after page is idle

Tags: angular, navigation, delay, router

I have a problem that I was wondering if someone knowledge to help me.

In my project, I have some link that work great just after I load the page. **But if I wait a minute or so before clicking the link, it takes a long time to change the route**.

Im using navigateByUrl inside a click event, the click event is working fine and the console.log inside it is logging, but when it tries to navigate, it takes a long time to change the route (3 minutes or more).

I tried like this (I saw this example in some site I don't recall)

```
console.log('tryToNavigate')
myRouter.navigateByUrl('/app/e', {skipLocationChange: true})
.then(
    (resp)=>{
        console.log('lastNavigation', resp);
        myRouter.navigateByUrl('app/company').then(
            (resp2) => console.log(resp2)
        );
    }
).catch((error)=>console.log(error));
```

I tried like this too Just in case

```
console.log('tryToNavigate')
myRouter.navigateByUrl('app/company').then(
    (resp2) => console.log(resp2)
).catch((error)=>console.log(error));
```

Even just the navigateByUrl alone doesn't work properly

```
myRouter.navigateByUrl('app/company')
```

[Log from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYhfn.png)

Is there something that I don't know of? Any way to debug it? Any light to show me the way?

Thanks

Comment: Still have'nt found a solution. Anyone knows anything about anything related to this problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a slash (/) before 'app/company'